# Vector Formulas Representation in Latex

Tags: vector

I want to write different formulas related vectors like subtraction, addition in latex, but don't know how to do this as I am new to Latex. I searched a lot but did not find any useful result.

Comment: You need to be much more specific - what exactly is it that you want to do but can't figure out?

Comment: I want to show formula for vector addition and subtraction in my report for that I need vector arrow on each variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can decorate a variable, say x, with a vector arrow using `\vec{x}` in math mode.

For a slightly more flexible definition (if you want, say, to have a vector whose name is more than one letter), you can put the following in the preamble of your document:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\ensuremath{\overrightarrow{#1}}}
```

Then you can use, say, `\vec{AB}`, and the arrow will stretch to cover both.